# How to add a character to beginning and ending of a String in C#?

Tags: c#, string, char, addition

I have a `string`, lets say it's `myStr = "My name is user something something";`

I want to change this string to:

```
'My name is user something something'
```

I want to convert the string from:

**My name is user something something**

to:

**'My name is user something something'**

I tried several methods but none worked, looks like easy but I'm missing something. Can you please make a code block which adds `"'"` character to beginning and ending of a string. Thank you.

Edit: My code;

```
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

         gecici = gecici + "'";//I think this adds to the ending
         sb.Append(gecici);
         sb.Insert(0, "'");// this to the beginning
         gecici = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Addet to the question, sorry.

Comment: Aside from the not-so-nice programming, I don't immediately see what the problem is with your code. Are you sure it does not work?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method:

```
myStr = "My name is user something something";
var newStr = string.Format("'{0}'", myStr);
```

Answer (score 3):

one way would be

```
   myStr = "'" + "My name is user something something" + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the value to be wrapped in single quotes as part of the value? Just add them like so:

```
string myStr = "'My name is user something something'";
```

If you're actually getting the string in the form of a variable and want to alter that, then do:

```
myStr = "'" + myStr + "'";
```